# Delete Hidden Rows in Table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I reviewed a couple of tickets and made some progress but am getting stuck. I started with this script below to delete any hidden/filtered rows.
This script works perfectly:

```
Sub RemoveHiddenRows() ' will delete all rows that are not visible
    Dim oRow As Range, rng As Range
    Dim myRows As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        Set myRows = Intersect(.Range("A:A").EntireRow, .UsedRange)
        If myRows Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    End With

    For Each oRow In myRows.Columns(1).Cells
        If oRow.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = oRow
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, oRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete
   End Sub
```

But then I needed to convert my range to a table. So I am trying to modify the script to do the same thing but for a table. So I updated to reflect the script below. I modified based on the feedback and am now getting this
Error message: **Delete method of range class failed.** on the last line.

```
Sub RemoveHiddenRows2() ' will delete all rows that are not visible
    Dim oRow As ListRow, rng As Range
    Dim myRows As Range
    Dim t1 As ListObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    
    With ActiveSheet
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
        Set t1 = ws.ListObjects("Staff")
       ' Set myRows = Intersect(ws.ListObjects("Staff").Range.EntireRow, .UsedRange)
       ' If myRows Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    End With

    For Each oRow In t1.ListRows 
    With oRow.Range.EntireRow
        If .Hidden Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = .Cells(1)
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, .Cells(1))
            End If
        End If
    End With
    Next

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete ' Getting stuck here.
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's a plain hidden row or a hidden row in a table or inside a filter. You can find it as a plan row and do what you need to to do. There are some questions/answers that address it. You could improve your code further if you catch up on some error handling too.

Answer (score 1):

`myRows` is a `Range`, which does not have a `ListObjects` property.

Just loop the rows in the table:

```
Dim rw As ListRow
For Each rw in t1.ListRows
    With rw.Range.EntireRow
        If .Hidden Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                 Set rng = .Cells(1)
            Else
                 Set rng = Union(rng, .Cells(1))
            End If 
        End If
    End With
Next
```

I suspect you can remove these lines.

```
Set myRows = Intersect(ws.ListObjects("Staff").Range.EntireRow, .UsedRange)
If myRows Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

If there's a table in the sheet, it will intersect with the used range.

Comment: Thank you for offering a solution. I was not able to get this to work. I get the error message "Object variable or With block variable not set" on the "For each rw In t1.Listrows line.

Comment: Do you still have the line `Set t1 = ws.ListObjects("Staff")`?

Comment: I do. I edited the code above with your feedback. I am getting a new error message on the last line.

Comment: What does `Debug.Print rng.Address` return in the Immediate Window? Do you have multiple tables on this sheet?

Comment: No, there is only 1 table on this sheet. I am not familiar with Debug.Print rng.Address.

Comment: Use Ctrl+G to open the immediate window.

Comment: Yeah but im not sure how you want me to run that.

Comment: You just add the line `Debug.Print rng.Address` immediately before the line currently throwing the error.